# Play The Sims 3 on Mac with Intel HD 3000

Tags: games, sim

Can I play The Sims 3 on my MacBook? It has only an Intel HD 3000 integrated graphics chip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That chipset is capable of running a hell of a lot more than The Sims, however you haven't stated your OS version, processor, or memory, but based on what MacBook systems have that graphics chipset, you shouldn't have any problems.

The minimum specs for the game are:

> Mac
>
> - Mac OS X v10.5.7 or later
> - Intel Core Duo processor
> - 2GB of RAM
> - 6.1GB of free hard-disk space minimum (with at least 1GB of additional space for custom content and saved games)
> - 128MB of VRAM
> - ATI X1600 or Nvidia 7300 GT or Intel Integrated GMA X3100
> - DVD drive
>
> Note: This game will not run on systems using PowerPC processors (G3/G4/G5) or the Intel GMA 950 class of integrated cards